# Out of Memory Errors on Windows 2008 Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v-server-2012, outofmemoryerror

I have a server which is configured as follows:

Physical Server (16GB RAM): Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition with Hyper-V Role installed

2 VMs running on this host server:
1 x Windows Server 2008 SP2 (64 bit) with the following RAM configuration:
    Currently assigned: 8192 MB
    Startup RAM: 4096 MB
    Dynamic Memory: Min RAM: 512 MB, Max RAM: 8192 MB
    Memory Buffer: 20%
    Memory Weight: (in the middle of scale)

1 x Windows Server 2008 SP2 (32 bit) with the following RAM configuration:
    Currently assigned: 1279 MB
    Startup RAM: 4096 MB
    Dynamic Memory: Min RAM: 512 MB, Max RAM: 1048576 MB
    Memory Buffer: 20%
    Memory Weight: (in the middle of scale)

The 2 VMs above were created by using the Disk2VHD physical-to-virtual converter tool.

I have also disabled the pagefile on the 1st VM above as I have read that it is managed by the 2012 Hyper-V host (I haven't disabled the pagefile on the 2nd VM yet).

The problem I am having is that I am seeing a lot of out of memory errors on the 1st machine. The server may become unresponsive and I will have to reboot it or I may see errors in the event log such as:

===============================================================================
COM+ has determined that your machine is running very low on available memory.  In order to ensure proper system behavior, the activation of the component has been refused.  If this problem continues, either install more memory or increase the size of your paging file.  Memory statistics are:

dwMemoryLoad = 49

ullTotalPhys = 0x1ffea4000

ullAvailPhys = 0x103e81000

ullTotalPageFile = 0x1f802e000

ullAvailPageFile = 0x009f0f000

ullTotalVirtual = 0x7fffffe0000

ullAvailVirtual = 0x7fffac60000

Process Name: w3wp.exe
Comsvcs.dll file version: ENU 2001.12.6932.18005 shp

===============================================================================

Looking at Task Manager on the 1st VM it always seems like there is plenty of physical RAM available and the above error in the Event Log backs this up. Currently its only using 3.36GB of the 8GB allocated.

Has anyone come across this kind of out of memory issue before when running Windows 2008 VMs on Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Host?

Perhaps I should re-enable the pagefile on the VM itself?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Re-enable the pagefile on VM1 and cite your source that states the guest pagefile is managed by the host.

Comment: Was about to post the same comment.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I'll re-enable it and see how it goes.

Comment: Let us know how this turned out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Re-enable the guest paging file.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/09/02/guest-paging-vs-virtualization-paging-and-negative-memory-availability.aspx

http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/q-i-notice-windows-server-2012-virtual-machines-have-smart-paging-file-location-what-smart-p

> The Smart Paging feature is used only to provide reliable restart of
>   VMs and isn't used in any other circumstance, including if a machine
>   is being started from off state instead of being restarted, or any
>   other memory overcommit scenario.

The VM host is still not smarter than the guest for paging decisions.

Answer (score 0):

I re-enabled the guest paging file and it seemed fine for a while but then the issues began again. I've had to change it back to fixed memory now and it is running fine. Not a solution I know but as there is only 1 VM on this server for the time being it isn't an issue.